# Classes with oracles forcing the caller to immediately accept (or reject)?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, polynomial-hierarchy

Usually an oracle operates as a black box, simply returning an yes or no answer to the machine calling it; once it has the result, the caller is free to proceed as it sees fit.

However, what happens if the caller *must* accept or reject (exactly one of the two) immediately as a function of the oracle's output? Say, for example, the caller has access to a SAT oracle, *but* must always accept (unconditionally) whenever the oracle answers with "yes"; this means the caller can continue its operation if and only if the query formula is unsatisfiable.

This imposes a restriction, obviously; are there cases in which this yields — or there is reason or evidence enough to suspect it yields — a strict subset of decision problems when compared to the "usual" behavior?

I am particularly interested in the case of $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}}$ or similar classes in the polynomial hierarchy, but other classes and oracles are relevant too.

Comment: Many-one reductions essentially do what you describe. Without them, you cannot distinguish between NP and co-NP, since you can always "flip" the oracle's answer, so they are essential in studying the polynomial hierarchy.

Comment: If you also allow sometimes reversing the answer of the oracle, you get what is called a "1-truth-table" or "1tt" reduction, which appears to be just slightly more powerful than many-one reductions, but still less powerful than full-on Turing reductions. You might be interested in the [Boolean Hierarchy](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:B#bh) in this regard.

Comment: @chazisop It's not quite a many-one reduction since the caller is allowed to continue its computation (on precisely one of the two accept/reject branches) once the oracle returns.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow It's not _quite_ a truth-table reduction (well, not at first sight); though I've managed to sketch a proof showing it's equivalent to it (at least in my special case). If you post the comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept  :)

Comment: Can the oracle's decision of whether-or-not it forces ​ "its caller to immediately enter an accept or reject state" ​ depend on prior queries too, or just on the current query? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer The oracle is stateless, so only if the input encodes the previous queries somehow.

Comment: If the reduction needs to work regardless of how the oracle exercises its right, then the oracle is useless, since the oracle could always force rejection, in which case one could replace querying with rejection. ​ If how the oracle exercises that right is specified like the oracle's responses, then I doubt your sketch is correct: The oracle could just never exercise that right, in which case one is back to Turing reductions. ​ (continued ...) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: (... continued) ​ If you insist that it actually exercise that right, then suppose it does so on the empty input and inputs that start with 0, and otherwise responds according to whether-or-not _the rest_ of the input is in some language. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky Demer I suppose the "oracle forces" formulation was a bit misleading (I'll edit that shortly). Essentially it's irrelevant _who_ forces it; the point is the caller is _only_ allowed to calculate further in case the oracle doesn't,  e.g., answer "no" to the query.

Answer (score 3):

The question is not entirely clear to me. However, concerning the example that is spelled out more precisely: if a language is recognizable by a poly-time machine with a SAT oracle which must accept whenever the oracle answers “yes”, it is in fact in NP. First, observe that regardless of the oracle answers, we can simulate in polynomial time the only possible run of the algorithm by pretending all answers are “no”. (In particular, we can compute the list of all oracle queries beforehand.) Then, the original algorithm accepts iff one of the oracle answers in the simulated run is actually “yes”, or the simulated algorithm accepts in the end. This is an NP property.

More generally, if we use an arbitrary oracle $A$ in the above scenario in place of SAT, a language can be computed in the indicated way iff it is poly-time dtt-reducible to $A$.

Comment: Put another way, any algorithm in this model can be immediately transformed into an algorithm in a simpler model, one where you only ask a single question of a different oracle (the concatenation of the questions along the only possible run in the original model).